# Java: How to readd delimiter back to string after reversing split word?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

After I reverse the split words, I am unsure on how to re add the delimiters.

```
String fileContent = "def  mnop.STU";
    String delimiter = "[^a-zA-Z0-9']+";
    String[] splitWords = fileContent.split(delimiter);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : splitWords) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
        stringBuilder.append(output);
    }
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
    joiner.add(stringBuilder);
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

Current output: `fedponmUTS`

Desired output: `fed  ponm.UTS`

Comment: you can still use yuor "fileContent"; since fileContent.split(delimiter) gives you new array of strings, using this it can't be possible to get back the original string such as fileContent.

Comment: @PapaifromBEKOAIL I'm not quite sure I follow. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very elegant, but could you do something like this?

```
for (String word : splitWords) 
{
    int idx = fileContent.indexOf(word, stringBuilder.length());
    String delim = fileContent.substring(stringBuilder.length(), idx);
    stringBuilder.append(delim);

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
    stringBuilder.append(output);
}
```

Output:

```
fed  ponm.UTS
```

Comment: This works. I hadn't thought of this approach. Thanks.